# why is thread not matching the words inside a map?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am doing a java program for counting the number of occurrences of each word in a file and entering them in a map. I am using threads concept.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;



class MyThread1 extends Thread
{  
    String word;
    int len,position;
    String[] wordlist;
    MyThread1(String word, int len,int position, String[] wordlist)
    {
        this.word=word;
        this.len=len;
        this.position=position;
        this.wordlist=wordlist;
    }
 public void run()
 {  
     int i=position,y,count=0;

       synchronized(this){
           Map<String,Integer> m=new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();

          if(m.containsKey(word))
        {
            System.out.println("Duplicate entry - bypassing it");
        }
        else{
        y=i+1;
        count=1;
        for(int j=y;j<len;j++)
        {
            if(word.equals(wordlist[j]))
                count++;
        }
      /*    if(m.containsKey(word))
        {
            int l=m.get(word);
            System.out.println("word is "+word);
            System.out.println("existing count "+l);
            System.out.println("current count "+count);
            if(l>count)
            {
                m.put(word, l);
            }
            else
            {
                m.put(word,count);
            }
        } */
        m.put(word,count);
           count=0;
        }

                for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> me:m.entrySet())
                {
                    System.out.println(me.getKey()+"  "+me.getValue());
                }  
       }
  }
 }


public class UsingThread
{
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
{
    File f1=new File("C:/Users/sahithim/Desktop/file1.txt");
    FileReader fr=null;
    int x;
    String s="",eachEntry="";
    try {
         fr=new FileReader(f1);
         while((x=fr.read())!=-1)
         {
             s=s+(char)x;
       }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        fr.close();
    }

    String[] wordArray=s.split(" ");
        int num_0f_words=wordArray.length;
        for(int i=0;i<num_0f_words;i++)
        {
            eachEntry=wordArray[i];
            MyThread1 mt1=new MyThread1(eachEntry,num_0f_words,i,wordArray);
            mt1.start();
        }



}  
    }
```

In this i am sending each word to a thread and checking for its existence in map. Even though the word is present in the map it is not recognizing it.

I am expecting an output like this

```
hey  24
hello  6
this  6
is  6
pallavi  6
nalam  6
sahithi
  6
i  12
am  6
good  6
love  6
flowers 6
```

It is printing some thing like this

```
hello  6
this  6
hey  24
  1
is  6
pallavi  6
nalam  6
hey  23
hey  22
hey  21
sahithi
  6
i  12
am  6
good  6
i  11
love  6
flowers
  6

  6
hey  20
hello  5
this  5
is  5
pallavi  5
nalam  5
hey  19
hey  18
hey  17
sahithi
  5
am  5
i  10
good  5
i  9
love  5

  5
flowers
  5
hey  16


  1
flowers
  1
is  4
i  1
this  4
good  1

  1
am  1
love  1
sahithi
  1
i  2
hey  2
hey  1
i  4
i  3
nalam  1
this  1
is  1
hey  4
hello  1
love  2

  2
am  2
flowers
  2
good  2
hey  5
sahithi
  2
hey  7
hey  6
nalam  2
pallavi  2
is  2
this  2
hey  8
love  3
i  5

  3
am  3
sahithi
  3
hello  2
nalam  3
hey  11
pallavi  3
this  3
hello  3
hey  10
hey  9
i  6
good  3
flowers
  3
pallavi  1
hey  3
hello  4
pallavi  4
nalam  4
hey  15
hey  14
sahithi
  4
hey  13
i  8
am  4
good  4

  4
i  7
love  4
hey  12
flowers
  4
is  3
```

What is the mistake i am doing ? How to get the required output ?

Comment: This is not a question, but a request for others to write code for you. You start one thread for each occurence of a word, instead of just one thread per word.

Comment: @tkruse i have no intention of assigning my work to others. I corrected the code and got the required output.

Answer (score 0):

You start one thread for each occurence of a word, instead of just one thread per word.

Answer (score 0):

> In this i am sending each word to a thread and checking for its existence in map. Even though the word is present in the map it is not recognizing it.

You are sending a word to a *new* thread which creates a *new* `LinkedHashMap` for each and every word.  I believe that you want to be using one single `LinkedHashMap` that you allocate in your `main` method.

```
Map<String,Integer> wordMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
...
MyThread1 myThread = new MyThread1(eachEntry, num_0f_words, i , wordArray, wordMap);
// then use this external map inside of the `run()` method
```

But this really does not look like a good use of `Thread` if you are creating a new thread for each and every word.  But maybe this is some sort of academic exercise?